# How to create arrays based on array of objects value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm working on a task where I've to make arrays based on certain values in array of objects.

Input Array:

```
const array = [{
        name: 'A',
        age: points: { x: 100, y: 107}
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        age: points: { x: 210, y: 107}
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        age: points: { x: 110, y: 107}
    },
    {
        name: 'D',
        age: points: { x: 230, y: 107}
    }
];
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    [
        {
            name: 'A',
            age: points: { x: 100, y: 107}
        },
        {
            name: 'C',
            age: points: { x: 110, y: 107}
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            name: 'B',
            age: points: { x: 210, y: 107}
        },
        {
            name: 'D',
            age: points: { x: 230, y: 107}
        } 
    ]
]
```

Note: here condition value will be dynamic, for example, the points following under certain conditions can be fall in one array, if that out of condition then-new array will be formed and so on, there may be 200+ objects in the array.

In case new object occur as

```
{
    name: 'D',
    age: points: { x: 230, y: 107}
}
```

then a new array of object ll be formed and all objects falling in that condition should get added to that.

Please put your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some example of condition

Comment: Are you aware of all possible conditions beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't completely clear. From what I can guess, you have an array of objects, you need to store an empty result array. Then, consume the "dynamic conditions" one by one, use a filter method on the original array and keep adding the results on to the result array.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
let dataArray = [<your objects>];
let resultArray = [];
while(<dynamic condtions list is not empty>)
{
    resultArray.push(dataArray.filter(item=>{
        // write your filter logic based on your current dynamic condition here
        if(item satisifes condition)
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }))
}
console.log(resultArray);
```